# Remove a specific string common in multiple lines in a CSV file using shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, csv

I have a CSV file which contains 65000 lines (size approximately 28 MB). On each of the lines they have a path in the beginning in the format of: **c:\abc\bcd\def\123\456**.

Now let's say the path **c:\abc\bcd\** is common in all the lines and the rest of the content is different. I have to remove the common part from all the lines. In this case, **c:\abc\bcd\**.

How can I remove this using a shell script?

Comment: Can you not simply replace the common part "c:\abc\bcd\" with ""?

Comment: Any text editor will be able to do the search & replace operation that duDE suggests, so do you really *need* a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and writing the output to a new file so it can be checked.

```
sed 's/c:\\abc\\bcd\\//' csv-file > new-file
```